# LocalStorage clearing on application restart

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webpack

I'm developing a project in Webpack, using vsCode, and I am storing objects in an array, and setting that array in localStorage. This array is called taskList. If a user creates a new task, I create a new object, call it newAddition, get the taskList array from localStorage, push newAddition to it, then set the taskList array back in localStorage. This only runs on a form submit(click event) and is stored in a seperate module ((I'm almost certain this isn't the problem):

```
const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList"));
taskList.push(newAddition);
window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskList));
```

Whilst the site is open everything is fine - i can add, delete etc. However, once i close down vsCode, when i restart, my array disappears from localStorage.

In my index.js file(webpack), I have the following code to either pull taskList back out of localStorage, or if it doesn't exist(your first visit), to create a blank array, but every time i restart vsCode, my array is gone. If i keep vsCode open, i can close/restart Firefox and my localStorage is intact. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList"));

if (taskList === null) {
  const taskListcreate = [];
  localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskListcreate));
}
```

Is there something in the default Webpack setup (or webpack.config.js or package.json) that would clear local storage on each restart of the application? I haven't knowingly added anything that would, but that's the only explanation i can currently think of.

Comment: Can you please share source codes that runs when application starts,

Comment: It could happen, that you clear `localStorage` on application start

Comment: Hi ndotie - it certainly seems like that is what's happening, but the only other time I'm 'setting' localStorage in my application is when a form runs to submit a new object, and thats on a user click. Index.js is my entry point.

Comment: Giving a self-answer to a question is fine here. What Joosep.P said in the comment under your now deleted answer, is rather the wrong way around for Stackoverflow, the answer should _not_ be contained in the question itself already.

Comment: I thought it was better to provide a separate answer for clarity of anyone else having the same problem, but was told to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the live-server extension in vsCode has a setting that uses a random port everytime it gets launched. So if this setting is enabled on your machine, you're going to get a fresh localStorage session on each run.

To fix , open settings.json in the live server extension and check for

```
"liveServer.settings.port": 0,
```

Replace the 0 with 5500 like so:

```
"liveServer.settings.port": 5500,
```

The 0 tells live-server to use a different port everytime it launches which explains the absence of any values in localStorage, because each time vsCode is accessing localStorage from a different port. By using 5500 specifically, you make sure that it uses port 5500 everytime.

Comment: Please don't answer your own question. Instead edit your question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering your own questions. It is even [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).